# IIS - Redirect to subfolder with mask

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I'm using IIS 10. I've a website that is reachable with `subdomain1.domain.com` and `subdomain2.domain.com` only on HTTPS protocol.

I would like to set up a rewrite rule only if request comes from `subdomain2.domain.com` where website should load the URL `subdomain2.domain.com/la/signin`. This last URL should be masked and not showed to the user.

I've tried a lot of rewrite rules and searched other suggestions on stackoverflow but every solutions did not worked for me, even without mask.

This one is just my last try without mask, but I've tried many other solutions:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="https://subdomain2\.domain\.com$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}/la/signin" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this rule. It will rewrite https://subdomain2.domain.com(/) to subdomain2.domain.com/la/signin.

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="la/signin" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="subdomain2\.domain\.com" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/)?$" />
                    </conditions>
       </rule>
```

[image]

Comment: In my case this rule is totally ignored. It keeps opening the page subdomain2.domain.com/signin (that actually exists). The application is made with Angular, do you think Angular routing could be involved in this?

Comment: I remember angular host in IIS also depend on URL rewrite, so it shouldn't ignore the rule. Have you modified order list? Just need to put it above your other rewrite rule.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the other rule.

Comment: Please enable failed request tracing and check whether why your rule get ignored.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis